# Include js file in jquery - updated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to include another js file in jquery. I have found this exmaple code and tried, but browser console give me this error.

**CODE**

```
        $.getScript( "js/balloon.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {

          console.log( data ); // Data returned
          console.log( textStatus ); // Success
          console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
          console.log( "Load was performed." );
        });
```

**ERROR**

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/EDIT/swf/js/balloon.js?_=1420941386739. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.**

What mistake I have made, can anyone tell me ? Thanks.

If there is another good example to include js file in js please suggest for me. Thanks again.

**UPDATED**

I also tried the code bellow but it included before the **js included in html**, any suggestion to make it included together ?

```
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "js/balloon.js";
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Comment: If you already have the script in your directory, why do you have to load it in? Can't you just use a `script` tag?

Comment: Try running your web page through a web server (i.e. `http://127.0.0.1/project/index.html`) rather than running it directly off a web browser.

Comment: @AstroCB because I have 20+ of js ... I only need one kind of js when my function need it

Comment: Depending on your situation and on how big the js files are it is often more efficient to combine your js files into one big js file and then cache it. But yeah pretty sure you need to run it from a server for it to work.

Comment: host your code on some server.currently what happening is.you are running the .html file directly from folder withoit hosting.thats why when you try to access the js file protocol is showing as file:// instead of htttp. you can run the same page on Internet Explorer, this will get run properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the script over a server. Also - by default, for security reasons, you can not load js(jsonp) from another domain. Check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17875201/1619821).

Answer (score 0):

host your whole folder of code on 
server.Currently what happening
is.you are running the .html file
directly from folder without
hosting.thats why when you tried 
to access the js file from html,the protocol is showing as file:// instead of
htttp:// you can run the same
page on Internet Explorer, this
will get run properly. Chrome has some security policies. That is the reason why it is not running on it.

Comment: @ImHappy does it helped?